# How to send gunzip stream to another server without decompressing on local side?

Tags: bash, gunzip

I've got this bash command:

`gunzip db.gz | ssh user@host mysql -uroot -ppassword db`

It works, but has a side effect of decompressing the `db.gz` file which then has to be recompressed. I want to leave the compressed file in tact. I did a man 'gunzip' but didn't see an option for anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to send the file over the network in its compressed form and to decompress the stream on the receiving side.

```
ssh user@host "gunzip | mysql -uroot -ppassword db" < db.gz
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. I had done something like it before but in reverse (from database server to local machine). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Gave the man page a second look. There is a `-k` or `--keep` option that does this. Man page says:

`Keep (don't delete) input files during compression or decompression.`

Comment: Careful with the semantics. The gunzip man page says "gunzip [...] **replaces** each file whose name ends with .gz, -gz, .z, -z, _z or .Z [...] with an uncompressed file without the original extension". That is, its normal mode of operation, without the -k option, is to create the uncompressed file from the compressed one and then *delete the compressed one.* That last deletion step is what is prevented with -k; the decompression happens in any case. As Ted says, if you want to send the compressed file simply do so; no gunzip necessary on the sending side.